# how to close add form jqgrid navgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, addition, nav

How do I close the add form before it opens for validation reasons. The code currently works at the right time but the form won't close itself it just hides the fields. Is there any other operation than $form.hide(); that would work better?

```
           $('#invAdj').navGrid('#jqGridPager',
               // the buttons to appear on the toolbar of the grid
               { edit: false,add:true, del: false, search: false, refresh: false, view: false, position: "left", cloneToTop: false },
               //edit
               {

               },
                //add (This isn't working right)
               {
                   afterShowForm : function ($form)
                   {
                       if(header==false)
                       {
                          
                           alert("Error");
                           //this just removes the fields not the form
                           $form.hide();
                       }
                   },
                   closeAfterAdd: true,
                   recreateForm: true,
                   errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                       return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
                   },
                   url: "InvAdj/Add"
               });

       });
```

Answer (score 0):

$form is the form element and not the modal window.

I recommend you to use beforeInitData and return false in case you do not want to show the modal form.

```
          //edit
           {

           },
            //add (This should work)
           {
               beforInitData : function ( form )
               {
                   if(header==false)
                   {
                      return false;                          
                   }
                   return true;
               },
```